# Custom Class not found weird error in Laravel 4 using PSR-4 Autoloading

Tags: php, laravel-4, autoload, autoloader, psr-4

In my custom class.

```
<?php
  namespace CustomHelpers\API;

class api {

  public function __construct()
  {
  }

  public function api_login($data =[])
  {
     $respond = $this->api_function('admin_login', $data);
  }

  public function api_function($name, $request, $data = [])
  {
    $url = $name;
  }
}
```

File structure:

```
-app
--CustomHelpers
---API
----api.php
```

Composer.json

```
 "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "CustomHelpers\\": "app/CustomHelpers"
    }

},
```

> Class 'CustomHelpers\API\App' not found

I've done what is in the manual but it the error is shown is weird because I don't have an **APP** inside my **API** folder. I use the command of `composer dump-autoload` Hope someone can help me.

**Update**

```
use CustomHelpers\API;

 public function login()
 {
   $new = new CustomHelpers\API\api();
   $session = $new->api_login(array('token'=>$token));
 }
```

Comment: So, why/where are you instantiate `CustomHelpers\API\App`?

Comment: I will update my question that uses that class in my controllers.

Comment: I use the custom helpers for login purposes to request data in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it myself.

> Class 'CustomHelpers\API\App' not found

This error up here is finds the class of App or the facade of App inside my customer helper class.

```
<?php
namespace CustomHelpers\API;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App; //I add this line and solve my problem

class api {

    public function __construct() {
    }

  public function api_login($data =[])
  {
    $respond = $this->api_function('admin_login', $data);
  }

  public function api_function($name, $request, $data = [])
  {
     $url = $name;
   }
}
```